# Where should I place helper function for unit tests?

Tags: python, unit-testing

In my unit test, I have some code that generates a random balance and desired allocation for each ticker inside `portfolio` list:

```
import random
import unittest

class TestPortfolio(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.portfolio = ["AAPL", "AMZN", "GOOG"]

        allocations = []
        balances = []
        for i in range(len(self.portfolio)):
            a = random.random()
            b = round(random.uniform(1.0, 10000.00), 2)
            allocations.append(a)
            balances.append(b)
        allocations = [round(i / sum(allocations), 4) for i in allocations]
```

If I want to reuse that piece of code for other unit tests, where should I place the function?

Comment: Move it to a function that you can call from where you need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can move the logic to a function that you can call from any test that you need

```
def get_allocations(portfolio):
    allocations = []
    balances = []
    for i in range(len(portfolio)):
        a = random.random()
        b = round(random.uniform(1.0, 10000.00), 2)
        allocations.append(a)
        balances.append(b)
    return round(i / sum(allocations), 4) for i in allocations]


class TestPortfolio(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.portfolio = ["AAPL", "AMZN", "GOOG"]
        self.allocations =  get_allocations(self.portfolio)
```

Comment: Great. I overthought the matter.